# Find all files that have been changed in the last 30 days and put them in a TAR

Tags: find, tar

So we've got a Staging Server without Git or any other versioning tool.

Now we want to push the changes to the live system.

I was thinking about `find`, using `-exec`.

I'm trying this: 
`find . -type f -mtime -30  -exec tar -czf changed.tar.gz {} \;`

But it only adds the last file. I want to ADD it to `changed.tar.gz` instead of completely overwriting it. How can I do that?

Comment: You see the last item because for each file, it makes the tar file and add that file into it. So, at the end, you only see the last file. if you want to use `exec`, you should append your files to your tar. for this, first make your tar, then use `rzf` to append. `-r --append` is the option for appending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `exec`:

```
find . -type f -mtime -30  -exec tar -czf changed.tar.gz {} \;
```

You can `pipe` to `tar` using `--files-from=-` and `--null`:

```
find . -mtime -30 -type f -print0  | tar czf changed.tar.gz --files-from=- --null
```

> --null
>
> ```
>        -T reads null-terminated names, disable -C
> ```
>
> -T,
>  
>   --files-from FILE
>
> ```
>        get names to extract or create from FILE
> ```

In the example above, the input filename is `-` - the input from the `pipe`

You can also `pipe` it using `xargs`

```
find . -type f -mtime -30 -print | xargs tar -czf changed.tar.gz
```